# Apply animation to remove a text

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, css-animations

I have implemented a nav tab-like view. Three buttons and when we click on one button the text corresponding to the other two buttons get hidden. But I want that when we update the text then we must be seeing some animation like fade in.

```js
var prevId = 1;
function updateView(id) {
    document.getElementById("subsec"+prevId).style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("subsec"+id).style.visibility = "visible";
    prevId = id;
}
```

```html
<div id="subsec1" >
  Tab 1
</div>
<button onclick="updateView(1)"></button>

<div id="subsec2" style="visibility: hidden">
  Tab 2
</div>
<button onclick="updateView(2)"></button>

<div id="subsec3"  style="visibility: hidden">
  Tab 3
</div>
<button onclick="updateView(3)"></button>
```

Can anyone help me with this. I have attached an example of how my view looks.
Example: I am currently on tab 3 and I click on tab 1 then tab 3 content should disappear but through animation and content of tab 1 must appear on-screen through animation only(like fade in).

Comment: Can you add your CSS to help complete this snippet?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius there is no external CSS. I have added CSS in the HTML itself

Comment: ok - there must be more markup than that - the buttons for instance?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius please check now

Comment: If the DIV elements are hidden then so too will be the button - how then are you to show that tab?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius apologies I made a mistake, I have corrected it. I hope you are able to get what I want to achieve here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [this from w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

Try adding css like

```
.fadeIn {
    animation-name: FadeIn;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.fadeOut {
    animation-name: FadeOut;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes FadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0%; }
    to { opacity: 100%; }
}

@keyframes FadeOut {
    from { opacity: 100%; }
    to { opacity: 0%; }
}
```

and then adding javascript like so:

```
var prevId = 1;
function updateView(id) {
    document.getElementById("subsec"+prevId).className = "fadeOut";
    document.getElementById("subsec"+id).className = "fadeIn";
    preId = id;
}
```

replace visibility: in html to opacity: 0%, and set the classes at the beginning if you want them to have animation at the beginning.

This is not optimalized.

Answer (score 0):

I had a little play about to show how you might use a slightly simplified HTML markup and a modified button `clickhandler` function to trigger adding new styles (animations) to your tabs.

The CSS animations here are very basic examples but should serve to illustrate the effect of fading in.

```js
const clickhandler=function(e){
  document.querySelectorAll('button[data-tab]').forEach(bttn=>bttn.classList.remove('activebttn') );
  document.querySelectorAll('div[data-tab]').forEach( div=>div.classList.remove('active','initial') );
  document.querySelector('div[ data-tab="'+this.dataset.tab+'" ]').classList.add('active');
  this.classList.add('activebttn');
}

document.querySelectorAll('button[data-tab]').forEach( bttn=>bttn.addEventListener('click',clickhandler) );
```

```css
div[data-tab]{
  background:white;
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  border-radius:1rem 0 1rem 0;
  box-shadow:0 0 1rem rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  margin:1rem auto;
  width:600px;
  min-height:400px;
  padding:1rem;
  opacity:0;
}
div[data-tab]:not(.active){
  display:none;
}
@keyframes fadein{
  0%   { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; background:whitesmoke; }
}
@keyframes fadeout{
  0%{ opacity:100%;display:block; }
  100%{ opacity:0%; background:white; display:none; }
}
@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
.active{
  animation-name:fadein, shake;
  animation-duration:1s, 1s;
  animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 250ms,750ms;
}
.hide{
  animation-name:fadeout;
  animation-duration:1s;
  animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 250ms;
}
.initial{
  display:block!important;
  opacity:1!important;
}
button{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  border-radius:1rem;
  border:1px solid transparent;
  width:200px;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:1rem;
  transition:ease-in-out 250ms all;
}
button:hover{
  border:1px solid gray;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
  box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
button:active,
.activebttn{
  border:1px solid gray;
  background:rgba(0,255,0,0.25);
}
```

```html
<button data-tab=1>Tab 1</button>
<button data-tab=2>Tab 2</button>
<button data-tab=3>Tab 3</button>



<div data-tab=1 class='initial'>
  Code finance. Let's put a pin in that one-sheet we need to button up our approach optimize for search nor my supervisor didn't like the latest revision you gave me can you switch back to the first revision?.
</div>
<div data-tab=2>
  We need to socialize the comms with the wider stakeholder community prairie dogging, roll back strategy drink the Kool-aid meeting assassin, but form without content style without meaning, yet can we jump on a zoom.
</div>
<div data-tab=3>
  Cloud native container based knowledge process outsourcing blue sky. Tribal knowledge. I called the it department about that ransomware because of the old antivirus, but he said that we were using avast 2021 let's schedule a standup during the sprint to review our kpis.
</div>
```